# Distance-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Hello all,

I have a few conjectures that I want to test concerning distance-regular graphs. They would be easy to test on a computer, but I am wondering whether anyone knows of a place where I can get a ton of sample intersection arrays, in some sort of computer format, to test? For example, in the book by Brouwer, Cohen, and Neumaier has a ton of them in the back, but entering them all would take forever. I'm wondering whether someone has already done it, and would mind sharing with me.

Greg

Comment: Perahps test your conjectures on the known classes of distance-regular graphs?  They are listed at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance-RegularGraph.html .

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/ (the web page of A. Brouwer) -- he has data, and I am guessing that he would be receptive to questions, as well.